# How to standardize a column based on values of columns using python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fill-up the column LOT_std in the following table. Row 1 already has standardized value in the LOT_std column, now I need to fill up blanks.

|  | Regimen | Line of Therapy (LOT) | LOT_std |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DrugA + DrugB + DrugC Q21C | LOT 1 | LOT1 |
| 2 | DrugA | maintenance |  |
| 3 | DrugA + DrugB | maintenance |  |
| 4 | DrugA + DrugB + DrugC | maintenance |  |

The rule is, if any subsequent row in the Regimen column contains one or more or all drugs from row 1 Regimen column and its Line of Therapy (LOT) is maintenance, then its Lot_std will be same as row 1. Therefore, the expected output would be:

|  | Regimen | Line of Therapy (LOT) | LOT_std |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DrugA + DrugB + DrugC Q21C | LOT 1 | LOT1 |
| 2 | DrugA | maintenance | LOT1 |
| 3 | DrugA + DrugB | maintenance | LOT1 |
| 4 | DrugA + DrugB + DrugC | maintenance | LOT1 |

Any idea how to implement this using python/pandas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the first value you could use `fillna` with method `ffill`

```
df["LOT_std"] = df["LOT_std"].fillna(method="ffill")
```

Comment: In order to use fillna for row 2/3/4, first I must make sure that row 2/3/4 regimen columns has any one/ two, or all of the drugs listed in row 1 of Regimen column. I am not sure how to implement that.